# Evaluate $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{x^7}{\cos^2 (x)} \,\rm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

the original function is $f(x)=(x^7 - x + 1)/cos^2 x$ and I need to evaluate $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (x^7 - x + 1)/cos^2 x dx$. so I broke it up to
$\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} (x^7 - x + 1)/cos^2 x = \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} x^7/cos^2 x dx - \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} x/cos^2 x dx + \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 1/cos^2 x dx$ but I can't evaluate $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} x^7/cos^2 x dx$. first I tried using $u = tan x \rightarrow du = dx/cos^2 x \rightarrow \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}arctan^7 u du$ but I don't know how to evaluate that either. then I tried $\int uv' = uv - \int u'v$ so $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} x^7/cos^2 x dx = x^7\cdot tanx - \int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} 7x^6 \cdot tan x dx$ but again I don't know how evaluate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = x^7 / \cos^2(x)$. Notice that

$$f(-x) = (-x)^7 / \cos^2(-x) = (-1) \cdot x^7 / \cos^2(x) = -f(x)$$

by the fact that $\cos(x)$ is an even function ($\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$). Then you have that $f(x)$, i.e. your integrand, is odd by the above.

Also, notice that the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval is $0$, i.e. $\int_{-a}^a g(x)dx = 0$ for all $a \in \Bbb R$ when $g$ is odd and integrable on $[-a,a]$.

Putting these two facts together lets you come up with a nice and easy way to find the answer to your problematic integral posed in the title.